# A consequence of Hewitt-Savage law

Tags: probability-theory

$\newcommand{\braket}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}$
$\newcommand{\ns}{\mathbb N^*}$
$\newcommand{\sn}{\left( S_n \right) _{n \in {\ns}}}$
$\newcommand{\san}{\left( \hat S_n \right) _{n \in {\ns}}}$
$\newcommand{\pr} {\mathbb P}$
$\newcommand{\sg} {\sigma}$
$\newcommand{\s} {\;}$
$\newcommand{\om} {\Omega}$
$\newcommand{\to} {\rightarrow}$
$\newcommand{\re} {\overline{\mathbb{R}}}$
$\newcommand{\bt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}$
$\newcommand{\pfrac}[2]{\left( \frac{#1}{#2} \right)}$
$\newcommand{\fa} {\forall}$
Hello everyone, I have doubts about understanding a passage from an
example of my book (example 5.19 Cinlar pag. 88)

**Example**

Let $ \left( \Omega, \mathcal{H}, \mathbb P \right)$
a probability space, $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N^*} $ a sequence
of random variables $X\equiv (X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N^*} $. Suppose that $X_{i}$
are indipendent and have the same distribution. Put

$$ S_n= \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb N^*$$

We want to show that if at least one of the $S_{i}$ is nonzero, then exactly one of the following three possibilities is almost sure:

(1) $\lim S_{n}=+\infty$

(2) $\lim S_{n}=-\infty$

(3) $\liminf S_{n}=-\infty$ and $\limsup S_{n}=+\infty$

**Reasoning**

Since for all $i$, $S_{i}$ is nonzero, then we havr $\pr\left(X_{1}=0\right)<1$.
Infact suppose that $\pr\left(X_{1}=0\right)=1$. Then $X_{1}=0$
q.o. and therfore $S_{1}=X_{1}$ $\s \Rightarrow \s $ $S_{1}=0 $ q.o. Than
we know that

$$\pr_{X_{2}}=\pr_{X_{1}}  \s \Rightarrow \s  \pr_{X_{2}}\left(\left\{ 0\right\} \right)=\pr_{X_{1}}\left(\left\{ 0\right\} \right)=1 
\s \Rightarrow \s X_{2}=0 \s \text{q.o.}$$

which implies

$$ S_{2}=X_{1}+X_{2}=0+0=0 \s \text{q.o.}$$

Similarly for all $n\geq3$ we obtain $S_{n}=0 \s \text{q.o.} $

So actually $\pr\left(X_{1}=0\right)<1$.

Now let be $V$ the map 
$$ V:\om \to \re $$
$$ V = \limsup \sn $$

We observe that:

$\bullet$ $V$ is in $\sg X$

$\bullet$ $V$ it's invariant under finite permutations

Therefore, by the Hewitt-Savage Law 0-1, ther is a $c\in\re$ such
that  $ \limsup S_{n}=c $. Now let $\san $ be the sequence defined by
$$
\hat{S}_{n} = S_{n+1}-X_{1}\quad\quad\fa n\in\ns
$$

**MY DOUBT**

The book asserts that " $ \san $ it's another random
walk that has **the same law** of $ \sn $". I've not understood what the author means by "same law". From what he says later, it seems to me that
$$
V=\limsup\hat{S_{n}}
$$
given that shortly after he asserts that 
$$ c=\limsup \san $$
In conclusion, I didn't understand why $V=\limsup \san$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that $V =\lim \sup (\hat {S_n})$. We can define $\hat {V}$ as  $\lim \sup (\hat {S_n})$ (and similarly, we can look at $\lim \inf (\hat {S_n})$) and   then can prove that 1), 2) or 3) holds by proving that the corresponding result holds for the new sequence $\hat {S_n}$. Ths is based on the following considerations:

Any sequence $(X_n)$ of random variables on a given probability space defines a measurable function from the space into $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ provided with its Borel sigma algebra. Hence there is an **induced measure** or the **distribution** of the sequence on $\mathbb R^{\infty}$. If two sequences $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ induce the same distribution then properties of one sequence can be translated to those of the other; for example, $\lim \sup X_n <\infty$ a.s.  iff  $\lim \sup Y_n <\infty$ a.s.. Some familiarity with these facts has been assumed in the book.

Comment: $\newcommand{\ns}{\mathbb N^*}$
$\newcommand{\sn}{\left( S_n \right) _{n \in {\ns}}}$
$\newcommand{\san}{\left( \hat S_n \right) _{n \in {\ns}}}$
$\newcommand{\pr} {\mathbb P}$

So, you're saying that $ V \neq \limsup \hat S_n$; but still remain to proof why $c= \limsup \hat S_n$. Any idea for this?
Also, when the book says "they have the same law" you believe it refers to the fact that $ \pr_{\hat V}=\pr_{V} $?

Comment: $\newcommand{\ns}{\mathbb N^*}$
$\newcommand{\sn}{\left( S_n \right) _{n \in {\ns}}}$
$\newcommand{\san}{\left( \hat S_n \right) _{n \in {\ns}}}$
$\newcommand{\pr} {\mathbb P}$

Finally, let's me add one thing. In the past few hours I have come up with a strategy to completely bypass this problem. In fact, I could distinguish the cases in which $ X_1 $ is constant and the case in which it is not. In the first case I arrive to verify that one of the following three conditions is true: 
$$ \lim S_n = +\infty $$
$$ \lim S_n = -\infty $$
$$ \lim S_n =0 $$

Comment: $\newcommand{\ns}{\mathbb N^*}$
$\newcommand{\sn}{\left( S_n \right) _{n \in {\ns}}}$
$\newcommand{\san}{\left( \hat S_n \right) _{n \in {\ns}}}$
$\newcommand{\pr} {\mathbb P}$


Now suppose that $ X_1 $ is not constant. Then put 
$d := \limsup \hat S_n$
we have $d=c-X_1$ and I come to conclude that $X_1$ is constant - a contradiction - or $ c= \pm \infty $. in this way I don' need that $d=c$